# スマホ用ドロップダウンjquery[Slimmenu] にて、最初からメニュー一覧を表示させたい

Tags: jquery

スマートフォン用ドロップダウンメニューができるjqueryです。
http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/

設定した幅以下になると、横並びのメニューが、横３本線のスマホ用メニューボタン１つに変わり、それをクリックすると、メニュー一覧が出る形です。

こちら、横３本線のスマホ用メニューボタンをつけず、最初からメニュー一覧が出てる状態にしたいです。(各メニュークリックで、下層メニューが出るなど、それ以外の動きは同じにしたい。)

同じ質問が本家にてされていますが、回答がありません
※初めての投稿なので、リンクを２個以上投稿できません。。

Answer (score 1):

Option に該当項目が無いので、標準機能では不可能な気がします。
jquery.slimmenu.js 自体を編集して良いのであれば、下記修正でいけると思います。

！注意事項
[MITライセンス](http://www.jshc.jp/slimmenu/)なので問題はないと思いますが、改変は（改変後の動作保証も含めて）自己責任でお願いします。
※一応ライセンスも再確認した方が良いと思います。

L.35あたり

```
$collapser = '<div class="menu-collapser">'+$options.collapserTitle+'<div class="collapse-button"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></div></div>',
```

を↓にする（スマホ用メニューボタンを削除）

```
$collapser = '<div class="menu-collapser">'+$options.collapserTitle+'</div>',
```

L.62～66あたり

```
$menu_collapser.on('click', '.collapse-button', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $menu.slideToggle($options.animSpeed, $options.easingEffect);
});
```

は使わないので削除（メニューボタンのイベントなので削除しなくても問題は無いです）

L.112あたり

```
$menu.addClass('collapsed').hide();
```

を↓にする（第一階層のメニューを隠さない）

```
$menu.addClass('collapsed');
```